# error: no newline at end of file [-Werror,-Wnewline-eof]#endif when apportable load work on my IOS Game

Tags: compiler-errors, clang, warnings, xcode4.6

My cocos2d iOS game code compiles and runs without error in Xcode 4.6.2 but apportable load stops with "No newline at end of file" error. for example:

> In file included from /Users/james/.apportable/SDK/System/dispatch/dispatch.h:28:sysroot/common/usr/include/stdint.h:42:7: error: no newline at end of file [-Werror,-Wnewline-eof]#endif

Comment: You cannot change that header file so you have no choice but to drop the `-Wnewline-eof` compiler argument.  I don't know why it's being used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can mess with the parameters that Apportable uses by going to "configuration.json" in your ".approj" folder, locating the section

```
// Edit this section to add and replace files and parameters to the generated settings for this project.
// If the generated settings for a particular file are incorrect, simply add it here with the settings
// you need and the final build parameters will only included the version specified here.
"add_params": {
```

and adding the flags you want in the "flags" array, like this

```
// A list of global compile flags for the project.
// Flags can be either a string, e.g. "-Werror-shadow",
// or a dictionary specifying the flag and the environment
// that it should be used in, e.g.,
// {"flag": "-fstack-protector", "env": {"TARGET_OS": "android"}}
"flags": [ "-Wno-four-char-constants", "-Wno-conversion", "-Wno-gnu", "-Wno-pedantic", "-Wno-selector", "-Wno-sign-conversion" ],
```

For this particular error, "-Wno-newline-eof" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It is really bizarre, but [apparantly](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/issues/5990#issuecomment-255860243) you need to have a trailing line at the end of the files! So just open the file you are compiling (`/Users/james/.apportable/SDK/System/dispatch/dispatch.h` or `sysroot/common/usr/include/stdint.h`) and just add an empty line, if it is not already there.